# How to search for and sort all lines found using vim?

Tags: vim, search, sorting

I have some c++ includes that I want to sort:

```
#ifndef t
#define t

#include <b>
#include <a>
#include <c>

#endif
```

I can `shift-v` to highlight the #include lines and then do `:sort` but I would like to do this with a simpler command if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the #include lines are delimited from the rest of the text by at least one blank line place the cursor on the start of the first #include line and enter:

```
!}sort
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
:command Psort :'{+1,'}-1sort
```

Then you should just be able to type `:Psort` to sort the paragraph (delimited by blank lines) that the cursor is on. (This has the advantage of working regardless of where the cursor is within the paragraph.)